# Помогите с алгоритмом "запотевания" картинки

Tags: алгоритм

Есть прямоугольная область, которая постепенно "запотевает". Как это лучше реализовать?

Если эту область частично "протирают" (допустим появляется круг на ней), как это реализовать?

Нужно ли хранить данные о касаниях в виде примитивов(круги, прямоугольники и т.п.) или лучше в виде плоскости?

Comment: Что именно Вы понимаете под реализацией? Алгоритм, который приводит непосредственно к запотеванию :) Или нужен алгоритм действий с цветами и слоями для какого либо графического редактора? Или алгоритм для программирования эффекта? Может нужно только для какой-то конкретной поверхности (для того же стекла) или до какой стадии поверхность должна запотеть?

Comment: Нужен алгоритм для прграммирования эффекта, который я потом реализую используя `OpenGL` под `Android` Я вижу это таким образом:Есть слой с полупрозрачной текстурой запотевшего стекла, наложив этот слой поверх любой картинки получаю полностью запотевшее стекло. Теперь нужно добавить еще несколько слоев сверху, которые будут произвольной прозрачности (пользователь протер поверхность от запотевшего), которые нужно как-то посчитать и объеденить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте моделировать процесс, похожий на физический. Запотевание стекла – это появление на нём микрокапелек конденсата. Это как точки, которые ложатся в случайных местах поверхности. С течением времени всё больше и больше точек. N точек в секунду.

Когда несколько капелек оказываются слишком близко друг от друга, они сливаются в более крупную каплю.

Когда стекло протирают, в следе все капли пропадают.

Капли я бы делал кругами, в которых реализуется какой-то эффект – размытия фона + блик/тень самой капли.

Касание / стирание я бы делал окружностью фиксированного диаметра.

Comment: Сначала я делал так: создал двумерный массив и обрабатывал его через определенные промежутки времени, добавляя новые капли возле существующих и объеденяя старые в более большие, но сложность моего решения - O(n^2),  не позволила его использовать (реально тормозила программа), сейчас я пытаюсь этот алгоритм оптимизировать.

Comment: Как упростить алгоритм? Думаю над использованием графов, но пока не готов приступить к реализации.

Comment: Я бы делал так. Каждая точка имеет две координаты: (x,y). Для быстрого поиска можно держать два одномерных сортированых массива X и Y, куда при добавлении очередной точки записывать её координаты по одной. Вернее, ключ- координата, значение - ссылка на точку. Так можно быстро найти точки из квадрата вокруг добавленной, и считать расстояния только до них, а не до всех.